# How to go to postback on change of @Html.EditorFor in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback

I have a `@Html.EditorFor` that represents a search field. I am trying to do a search in the controller when the text in the field is changed.
I can't figure out how to go to the postback every time the text is changed in the input, and not when the submit button is clicked.

Model:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    [Key]
    public int MainWindowId { get; set; } 
    public string SearchedString { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <label>search:</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchedString, new htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchedString, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })      
        <input type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "MainWindowId,SearchedString")] MainWindow mw)
{
    ManageProduct mp = new ManageProduct();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       //search code
        return View("Index",mw);
    }
    return View(mw);
}
```

Comment: What you want, autocomplete kind of functionality?

Comment: You should use ajax request from javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX to submit the form. I will use jQuery in my example.

Listen to changes of the `<input>` rendered by the Editor.

**EDIT:** To achieve this, we use the ID that the editor gave to the HTML input as jQuery selector (do not change the ID, because the MVC modelbinder expects it to be in a certain format). Find the ID using the browser Developer Tools (F12).

You will also need to give an ID to the form element so we can serialize it to get the post data. Also provide a placeholder into which to render the results.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "YourController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formId" })) {

<div id="placeholderId"></div>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchedString, new htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

JS function to post the form, embedded in the razor view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postForm() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#formId').attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#formId').serialize(),
        success: function(resultData) {
            if (resultData) {
                // update some placeholder element with the received data
                $('#placeholderId').html(resultData);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

JS to listen to changes of the input, embedded in the razor view. Listen to the `keyup` event, because `change` will only fire after the input loses focus. Here I assume that the editor gave `id="SearchedString"` to the input (may vary, e.g. if this is rendered as partial view).

```
$('#SearchedString').on('keyup', function () {
        postForm();
});
</script>
```

To prevent your server beeing swamped with request while the user types, take a look at [jQuery.debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/)

Comment: I tried what @Georg Patscheider said, and the listener was never reached. How do i connect the listener to the input?

Comment: Please make sure the input has the css class `searchInput`.

Comment: This is how the input looks: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchedString, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control searchInput" } })`

Comment: Maybe the class was not rendered as expected, this may depend on your EditorTemplate. I changed my answer so you can use the ID of the input, which you have to find out using the F12 tools.

Comment: What if you have a table and you are adding new rows and there isn't an ID for a new row? How do I listen for table updates?

Comment: The method that adds the new row to the DOM should also register any listeners that need to be aware of the content of the row. You might need to give unique IDs to the elements in the new row when adding them. Please ask a new question to get a full answer